# Fakes does not exist in the namespace System C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a mock testing for a C# .NET Core version 8 project with MSTesting. The library uses static methods that I want to fake in my test project. I found online about using Moles (shims) with the following syntax:

```
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet = () => new DateTime(1837, 1, 1);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Error
}
```

However, I can't figure out (after reading the documentation and other posts) how to add Fakes to System.Runtime.

Many instruction says in Visual Studio, you do Add > Add Fakes to the project assembly, but no further instruction. But I don't find this option at all. How to use System.Fakes in .NET Core MSTest project to fake static methods, if there is no way, is there an alternative way to make a mock tests on this?

Comment: In case of .NET 8 gladly we have `TimeProvider` , which makes the mocking of time an easy task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76016671/13268855

Comment: Mocking DateTime is just an example. I want to mock static methods from my own library.

Comment: This other question relates to .NET Framework 4.5.2, so I am not sure if the answers apply to your problem: [ShimDateTime not available in System.Fakes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40039081/880990).

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves well then Fakes was popular around a decade ago (Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 era).

Since then a lot of things happened to .Net and there are proprietary (like JustMock) and open-source alternatives (like [Pose](https://github.com/tonerdo/pose)):

```
using Pose;

Shim dateTimeShim = Shim.Replace(() => DateTime.Now).With(() => new DateTime(2004, 4, 4));
```

It has limitations but I think it's worth a try. Also worth mentioning that JustMock have a free [Lite](https://github.com/telerik/JustMockLite) edition as well.

Comment: Using Pose works, thank you!

Comment: @KaungZan I'm glad to read. If you have found my post useful then please consider to accept as the answer and/or upvote it. Thanks and have a great day!